# usage of terms "as well as " and "as well"

Tags: phrases, word-usage, writing, phrase-usage

Can anyone describe the usage of the terms "as well as" and "as well" in sentences? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

> 1) 'John is coming *as well as* Henry'.
>
> 2) 'John is coming, and Henry *as well*'

Does that help?

Comment: John as well as Henry is coming. Is that right?

Comment: John, as well as Henry, is coming. Is that right?

Comment: We have an [ell.se] as well.

Comment: ... Self-referencing smarty-pants.